# What will happen we pass -1 as value for 3rd parameter in strncmp() ie. n number bytes of bytes to compare?

Tags: c, cross-platform, memcmp, strncmp

I have three questions,

1. What will happen we pass -1 as value for 3rd parameter in strncmp() ie. n number bytes of bytes to compare?
2. Why the output differs in ARM and PPC? ie. if which one correct?
3. If I use memcmp instead of strncmp, I m getting "inside else" output in both ARM and PPC. How and why?

   ```
   char str[10];

   memset(str,'\0',sizeof(str));

   printf("str:%s ,len:%d\n\r",str,strlen(str));

   if(strncmp(str,"Maximum",(strlen(str)-1)) == 0)    
   {         
       printf("inside if\n\r");     
   }   
   else    
   {    
       printf("inside else\n\r");    
   }
   ```

Output in ppc

```
str: ,len:0
inside else
```

Output in arm

```
str: ,len:0
inside if
```

Comment: The third argument to `strncmp()` is of type `size_t`, which is unsigned.

Comment: Since one of the strings is empty, you're comparing 0 characters from one against 0 characters from the other regardless of the limit (but without the guarantee of equality that you'd have if the _limit_ was 0).

Comment: What don't you understand what is not descibed in the both functions'  documenation? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html

Comment: `strlen(str)-1` mostly ever is a route into to desaster. What do expect this to return for a "string" of length 0? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html

Comment: What's with the recent fascinatinon for doing obviously stupid things and asking which particular brad of stupid ensues?  'which one correct' - are you kidding me???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's another 'I drove my car into a tree, why am I in hospital?' question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What will happen we pass -1 as value for 3rd parameter in strncmp()

Assuming the 3rd parameter is defined a being of `size_t`and furthermore assuming `size_t` is defined as `unsigned` integer, passing in `-1` will result in a "wrap-around" and the function will receiving the value of `SIZE_MAX`. On a 32bit system this probably would be `0xffffffff`.